# How to compare multiple things at once

Tags: python, operator-precedence

let's say a='hi'

I want to know if a is any of the following 'hi', 'yes', or 'no'
I could just run

```
a='hi'
a=='hi' or a=='yes' or a=='no'
>>>True
```

But let's say it is a really long list of possibilities so I just say

```
a='hi'
a==('hi' or 'yes')
```

When I do this I get the answer True
But when I do something like this:

```
a==('yes' or 'hi')
>>>False
```

and then this is also weird

```
a==('yes' and 'hi')
>>>True
```

but if I switch them around again

```
a==('hi' and 'yes')
>>>False
```

Can someone explain what is happening here

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason why some of your lines evaluate to `True` while the others evaluate to `False` is simply due to [how `and`/`or` work in Python](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations):

> The expression `x and y` first evaluates x; if x is false, its value
>   is returned; otherwise, y is evaluated and the resulting value is
>   returned.
>
> The expression `x or y` first evaluates x; if x is true, its value is
>   returned; otherwise, y is evaluated and the resulting value is
>   returned.

Thus, let's walk through your cases.

```
('hi' or 'yes')
```

`'hi'` is truthy, so this expression evaluates to `'hi'`. `a == 'hi'` evaluates to `True`.

```
('yes' or 'hi')
```

Same reasoning, except now it evaluates to `'yes'`. `a == 'yes'` is `False`.

```
('yes' and 'hi')
```

Since `'yes'` is truthy, the expression evaluates to `'hi'`, and `a == 'hi'` is `True`.

```
('hi' and 'yes')
```

Finally, since this evaluates to `'yes'`, `a == 'yes'` is `False`.

If you want to test if a string is one of multiple things, test if it's in a set:

```
if a in {'hi', 'yes', 'no'}:
    # Do something
```

Answer (score 3):

This should answer your question:

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Dec  3 2013, 09:19:11) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.2.79)] on darwin
>>> ("yes" or "hi")
'yes'
>>> ("hi" or "yes")
'hi'
>>> ("yes" and "hi")
'hi'
>>> ("hi" and "yes")
'yes'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the python documentation bit about Boolean Operations, it explains this behavior https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html

```
These are the Boolean operations, ordered by ascending priority:

Operation   Result  Notes
x or y  if x is false, then y, else x   (1)
x and y if x is false, then x, else y   (2)
not x   if x is false, then True, else False    (3)
Notes:

(1) This is a short-circuit operator, so it only evaluates the second argument if the first one is False.
(2) This is a short-circuit operator, so it only evaluates the second argument if the first one is True.
(3) not has a lower priority than non-Boolean operators, so not a == b is interpreted as not (a == b), and a == not b is a syntax error.
```